# Как передавать данные из ByteArrayOutputStream в ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, io

Нудно в одном методе посылать в поток `ByteArrayOutputStream` массив байтов и тут же принимать в `ByteArrayInputStream`. Пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
public void rW() {
    byte[] bytes = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    byte[] outputArray = new byte[4];
    try (OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out)) // но он требует массив байтов
    {
        out.write(bytes);
        int b;
        while ((b = in.read(outputArray)) != -1) {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(outputArray));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Получается, что я не могу напрямую в конструктор входного потока положить объект выходного.
Так как же мне тут быть? Как мне использовать классы `ByteArrayOutputStream` и `ByteArrayInputStream` в одной связке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, вы не совсем верно представляете себе работу с потоками данных (i/o streams).

`InputStream` и `OutputStream`  - это абстракции последовательного доступа (чтения и записи, соответственно) к потоку данных. Конкретная реализация все же должна эти данные иметь в какой-то конкретной форме.

`ByteArrayOutputStream` - это абстракция для последовательной записи в массив байтов. Ее используют, чтобы написать произвольное количество данных в массив и получить его в конечном счете, вызвав метод `toByteArray()`.

`ByteArrayInputStream` - это абстракция для последовательного чтения из массива. Естественно, что массив для нее нужен вполне конкретный и осязаемый, иначе откуда поток будет читать данные?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53815/discussion-between-nofate-and-).

Answer (score 2):

Вообще по фэншую для таких целей существует пара потоков `PipedInputStream/PipedOutputStream`

В `PipedOutStream` пишутся байты и извлекаются из `PipedInputStream`

Они специально предназначены для коммуникации в мультитредовом приложении.